# FileNotFoundException when getting thumbnail from video ANDROID

Tags: java, android, video, bitmap, filenotfoundexception

I have a problem when I'm trying to get video thumbnail from phone gallery videos. I have a method which is getting bitmap of video thumbnail,but this method is not working perfectly. The minus of mine method is that,for some videos it's not working and I'm getting "FileNotFoundException",but for some videos this method is working fine.

```
 private void pickVideosFromGallery() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, SELECTED_VIDEO);
}

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK){
        return;
    }
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case SELECTED_VIDEO:
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap bit = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
            break;
```

}}

```
07-16 20:11:49.647 32387-32387/com.example.tstv.keepfavoritevideos E/folderFragment: Video Path: android.graphics.Bitmap@71d9de1
07-16 20:12:49.992 32387-32387/com.example.tstv.keepfavoritevideos E/MediaMetadataRetriever: setDataSource - FileNotFoundException
07-16 20:12:49.992 32387-32387/com.example.tstv.keepfavoritevideos E/folderFragment: Video Path: null
```

As you can see from that LOG, for some videos its working, and I am getting bitmap,but for some its not working. WHY?

Comment: There is no requirement for `DATA` to contain a filesystem path that your app has access to. Ideally, you would use an image-loading library like Picasso that knows how to handle video thumbnails. Otherwise, [use `getThumbnail()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.html#getThumbnail(android.content.ContentResolver,%20long,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)), which does not require your app to have to work with filesystem paths.

Comment: @CommonsWare you told that Picasso knows how to handle video thumbnails. Ok. I have video path ("/storage/emulated/0/viber/media/Viber Videos/video-0-02-05-593ae10fcc529a61219105e40c0dcf55a8fd8aed3e969543f04fa9c6c935e3ab-V.mp4"), how i can use it to load image by Picasso?

Comment: "I have video path" -- more importantly, you have a `Uri` from the `ACTION_PICK` operation. Supply that `Uri` to Picasso. Typically, Picasso is used to populate an `ImageView`, though there is a mechanism to get a `Bitmap` directly if you need that for some reason. While [the Picasso docs](http://square.github.io/picasso/) focus on HTTP URLs, `Uri` values work fine, and Picasso knows to grab video thumbnails. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/RecyclerView/VideoList) loads all videos into a `RecyclerView`, including thumbnails.

Comment: @CommonsWare i tried that method. It's still not working. I even can't play video from that "crash" video path. So problem is with that uri. The question is WHY and how to fix that?